# Azure Devops sprint taskboard - see the epic name of each PBI

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops allows to see PBIs and their associated tasks on sprint taskboard. But what if I want to see the associated Feature or Epic of each PBI? How about adding a new field to each PBI to see their related Epics?
I want to see the Epic on each card(list view of PBI) not by opening each PBI.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **Parent field**.

If you click on the settings icon, you can add the parent field. However, you can only go one level up, there is no "parent's parent" field to use.

e.g. if you use the (Epic -> Feature -> Backlog Items) structure, you can use this to show the **Feature**. You cannot display the Epic this way, there is no corresponding Field for it.

[image]

Comment: The parent field shows the feature, not the epic.

Comment: Yes I know, I updated my answer to make it clearer.